# Gitlab CI: Persist MySQL data between stages

Tags: php, mysql, docker, gitlab-ci

How do I persist MySQL data between different build stages?

I have MySQL set up as a service however, when going from a build to a deploy stage the MySQL database is empty and I'm unable to find any information on this.

Example `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: php:latest
services:
  - mysql:5.6
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - [INSERT MYSQL DATA]
  allow_failure: false
  artifacts:
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - /var/lib/mysql/
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - [MYSQL DUMP]
  dependencies:
    - build
  allow_failure: false
  when: on_success
```

The MySQL dump would be empty despite successfully inserting the data at the build stage.

Answer (score 5):

As per the Gitlab issues page: [Share service between build stages](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15524).  The way that Gitlab-CI is set up is such that:

> each job is run in each job is run independently of the others,
>   including potentially running on different machines. And the services
>   are run locally on each runner. There's no way for one job to access a
>   service on a different runner. On GitLab.com, we even recycle the
>   machine after each job runs so the services would all be destroyed.
>   @markpundsack

Although that is 7 months old, the issue is still open at this time.  The issue of getting the data from `mysql` is also a problem as services do not mount volumes (I do not believe any plans exist to add this feature), so the data is stuck inside the `mysql` container.

So you can handle this in a couple of ways:

1. Have the `setup` and `test` in the same job
2. Create an SQL docker with all data added already (bad practice but if you need it)
3. Create the dump in `setup` and share as artifact then reload that data with `test`

EDIT: Adding a note that using the [`expire_in`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#artifacts-expire_in) component for artifacts may be useful as you don't want to store a bunch of data you may not need forever.

EDIT2:
After researching some more, I found [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/mysql/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) by gitlab.  You can do the following:

```
services:
- mysql
variables:
  # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: hello_world_test
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql
connect:
  image: mysql
  script:
  - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql "$MYSQL_DATABASE"
  - SOME DATABASE DUMPING
 artifacts:
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - /var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: Is it not possible to share the data from `/var/lib/mysql` on the mysql service into the host container and use that as an artifact?

Comment: The `/var/lib/mysql` you would need to access of the service.  When using `artifact` you are doing it for the current image.  You could try and have `mysql` as the image for a build step

Comment: Made edit to answer to include a documented case by gitlab.  With that you can populate the database, then share the output as an artifact.